# Как правильно сделать push после --amend

Tags: git, github

Работая с git я сделал commit. После чего сделал push его на githab. Через некоторое время решил сделать исправление и попробовал сделать команду commit --amend. Раньше ей не пользовался, а просто делал новый коммит. Команда прошла и решил так же сделать push. Но git ругнулся на конфликт - файлы изменились. Я думал что он просто заменит исправленный коммит на удаленной ветке. Как теперь запушить его на github? Ветку, с момента первого пуша, с гита точно еще никто не скачивал и не работал на ней, коммиты никто не добавлял.

Comment: Неправильный коммит лучше затереть

Answer (score 0):

В инструкции намекают на `pull`. Она делает `fetch` и потом слияние. Потом можно будет и `push` делать.

Сервер :

```
A -> B
```

Вы с `commit --amend` :

```
A   -> B'
  \
   \-> B
```

Делаем `pull` и `push` :

```
A   ->  B' ->  C
  \          ^
   \->  B  -/
```

А удалить коммит всегда успеете. После того, как все удалённые контакты на коммит `B` уйдут дальше.